# User Favorites System in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

First sorry for my English;

For learning purpose I have create a blog with authentication ( I am using Devise), Now I want that user to be able to Favorited other users posts so when they visit the Favorited posts pages they will see posts saved. I appreciate if somebody can give me a tutorial link or guide me

Answer (score 1):

For adding a feature to enable users to favorite other users post you will need to create an association with the User and Post models that you might already have created

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  has_many :favorites, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :favorite_posts, :through => :favorites, :source => :post
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many   :favorites, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many   :favorited, :through => :favorites, :source => :user
end

class Favorite < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post
end
```

You can use these models to add the necessary features and create posts and favorites using this associations.

For example:
myname = User.create (:name => 'user333')
yourname = user.create (:name => 'user444')

mypost = myname.posts.create (:head => 'Hello', :body => 'post content')
yourname.favorites.create (:post => mypost)

This code will now give the favorite posts of user444 if you do
myname.favorite_posts

There are tutorials on creating bookmarks, following other users and creating favorites on the web like
http://doblock.com/articles/creating-an-extensible-user-favorites-system-in-rails
http://12devs.co.uk/articles/writing-a-web-application-with-ruby-on-rails/

Good luck !!

Comment: i have do what you tell me and i have create a fvorite controller                                                        def create
  current_user.favorites.create(params[:post_id])
end                                                                                                             this is routes                                                                        get "favorites/create"                                                               and i have add a button to posts                                        <%= button_to 'Add to Favorites', favorites_create_path %>

Comment: and this is my view                                                          <%= post_title.current_user.favorites%>                                 but when click to the add button and go to favorite path i get this error undefined local variable or method `post_title'

Comment: Is post_title defined in your Post model ?